# How to add an order by to a query

Tags: java, postgresql, ebean

I am trying to add an orderBy to an Ebeans query, and I am somewhat unfamiliar with this ORM.

This is my query:

```
    List<UserOffer> userOffers = Ebean.find(UserOffer.class)
            .fetch("offer")
            .where()
            .eq("user_id", userId)
            .eq("status_id", offerViewedStatus)
            .orderBy("updated_at")
            .findList();
```

Everything worked (and was written by a developer more experienced with Ebeans than me) before adding the orderBy, but as soon as I do, the query stops working.

Is there some sort of syntax issue I am missing?

The UserOffer class is based on the user_offer table which has the column updated_at which is a timestamp with timezone field.

The backend is Postgres.

Comment: "Stops working"? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding **asc** and **desc**

```
 List<UserOffer> userOffers = Ebean.find(UserOffer.class)
        .fetch("offer")
        .where()
        .eq("user_id", userId)
        .eq("status_id", offerViewedStatus)
        .orderBy.asc("updated_at")
        .findList();
```